# NodeJS deserialization from a stream

Tags: json, node.js, stream, deserialization

I am having an issue deserializing from a stream in node (specifically the pricing feed from the Bitcoin GOX exchange). Basically a chunk arrives which is **well formed complete and verified JSON**. Here is the code:

```
var gox = require('goxstream');
var fs = require('fs');
var options = {
    currency: 'AUD',
    ticker: true,
    depth: false
};

var goxStream = gox.createStream(options);
goxStream.on('data', function(chunk) {

    console.log(JSON.parse(chunk));
});
```

When trying to parse it I get the following

```
undefined:0

^
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

Any ideas? I have included a sample chunk:

```
> {"channel": "eb6aaa11-99d0-4f64-9e8c-1140872a423d", "channel_name":
> "ticker.BTCAUD", "op": "private", "origin": "broadcast", "private":
> "ticker", "ticker": {
>     "high": {
>         "value": "121.51941",
>         "value_int": "12151941",
>         "display": "AU$121.51941",
>         "display_short": "AU$121.52",
>         "currency": "AUD"
>     },
>     "low": {
>         "value": "118.00001",
>         "value_int": "11800001",
>         "display": "AU$118.00001",
>         "display_short": "AU$118.00",
>         "currency": "AUD"
>     },
>     "avg": {
>         "value": "119.58084",
>         "value_int": "11958084",
>         "display": "AU$119.58084",
>         "display_short": "AU$119.58",
>         "currency": "AUD"
>     },
>     "vwap": {
>         "value": "119.80280",
>         "value_int": "11980280",
>         "display": "AU$119.80280",
>         "display_short": "AU$119.80",
>         "currency": "AUD"
>     },
>     "vol": {
>         "value": "249.73550646",
>         "value_int": "24973550646",
>         "display": "249.73550646\u00a0BTC",
>         "display_short": "249.74\u00a0BTC",
>         "currency": "BTC"
>     },
>     "last_local": {
>         "value": "118.50000",
>         "value_int": "11850000",
>         "display": "AU$118.50000",
>         "display_short": "AU$118.50",
>         "currency": "AUD"
>     },
>     "last_orig": {
>         "value": "108.99500",
>         "value_int": "10899500",
>         "display": "$108.99500",
>         "display_short": "$109.00",
>         "currency": "USD"
>     },
>     "last_all": {
>         "value": "118.79965",
>         "value_int": "11879965",
>         "display": "AU$118.79965",
>         "display_short": "AU$118.80",
>         "currency": "AUD"
>     },
>     "last": {
>         "value": "118.50000",
>         "value_int": "11850000",
>         "display": "AU$118.50000",
>         "display_short": "AU$118.50",
>         "currency": "AUD"
>     },
>     "buy": {
>         "value": "118.50000",
>         "value_int": "11850000",
>         "display": "AU$118.50000",
>         "display_short": "AU$118.50",
>         "currency": "AUD"
>     },
>     "sell": {
>         "value": "119.99939",
>         "value_int": "11999939",
>         "display": "AU$119.99939",
>         "display_short": "AU$120.00",
>         "currency": "AUD"
>     },
>     "item": "BTC",
>     "now": "1376715241731341" }}
```

You can verify it here: http://jsonlint.com

Also it is probably worth mentioning I have already tried parsing and removing the escaped characters. Also have tried a couple of different serializers with the same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting two separate chunks (or at least: that's what I am getting when re-creating your issue). One (the first) is a valid JSON object, while the other (the second) is "almost empty": it is a 1-byte string containing just an `LF` (ASCII 0x0a).

The second one fails parsing, of course.

Read my first answer: this is exactly such a case. If you concat the two chunks together you get a complete JSON object with a trailing `LF`, easily passing `JSON.parse()`. If you try to parse the chunks separately, though, however, the first one succeeds (a trailing `LF` is not a mandatory) while the second one fails (an `LF` by itself is not a valid JSON object).

For your case, you would have to:

1) Either assume Mt.Gox always sends data "this way", ignore those "almost empty" chunks, and parse only the "non empty" chunks.

2) Or use `JSONparse` which parses JSON streams.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the data *chunk by chunk*. Chunks themselves may not be complete JSON objects. Either buffer all of the data, or use something to do it for you (say the `request` module), or if you need to parse a long stream take a look at the `JSONparse` module.

Comment: The chunks are complete as per the data dump I gave.

Comment: Not really. See my new answer.